# Multiple rows to one row Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following table

```
P_ID, PROGR, DATA  
 1  ,  1   , 'DATO A'
 1  ,  2   , 'DATO B' 
 1  ,  3   , 'DATO C' 
 2  ,  1   , 'DATO D' 
 2  ,  2   , 'DATO E' 
 3  ,  1   , 'DATO G'
```

and I want to get this result

```
P_ID,   DATA  ,  DATA_1 ,  DATA_2
 1  , 'DATO A', 'DATO B', 'DATO C'
 2  , 'DATO D', 'DATO E',   NULL   
 3  , 'DATO G',   NULL  ,   NULL
```

this can be done with a left join with the same table, something like this (not the exact result, but as an example)

```
select * from
(select * from MYTABLE where PROGR = 1) a
left join 
(select * from MYTABLE where PROGR = 2) b
on a.P_ID = b.P_ID
left join
(select * from MYTABLE where PROGR = 3) c
on a.P_ID = c.P_ID;
```

The problem is that this query is fixed, and need to be rewritten if some P_ID get PROGR = 4. I think that I need to make a procedure, but I have been trying without success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.pid,
       max(case when t.progr = 1 then t.data end) as data_1,
       max(case when t.progr = 2 then t.data end) as data_2,
       max(case when t.progr = 3 then t.data end) as data_3
from mytable t
group by t.pid;
```

To handle a variable number of columns, I can think of three solutions:

1. Put in enough columns to handle your data (some reasonable maximum).
2. Use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate` in PL/SQL).
3. Or, combine them into a single column.

Here is the last approach:

```
select t.pid, listagg(t.data, ', ') within group (order by t.progr)
from mytable t
group by t.pid;
```

Comment: Thats a good approach, but like the last sentence say, what happen if now I have progr 4 in some row, or then progr 5. The variable number of output columns is not a problem.
Thanks for the answer, I have learned something new.

Comment: With dynamic SQL would be the best. Can you give me an example?. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use below query.

```
select p_id,max(data_1) as data_1,max(data_2)as data_2,max(data_3) as data_3
    from
    (select P_ID,
    case when progr=1 then 
    data
    end data_1,
    case when progr=2 then 
    data
    end data_2,
    case when progr=3 then 
    data
    end data_3
    from thursday_check)
    group by p_id
```